# Getting error while running mvn test with variables

Tags: selenium, maven, automated-tests, cucumber-java

I am able to trigger my cucumber tests with tags tag1 and tag2 with the below command

```
mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src/main/resources/testng/runner-testng.xml -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@tag1 or @tag2"
```

This works.

Now I modified it like this :

```
tag="@tag1 or @tag2"
command="-Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src/main/resources/testng/runner-testng.xml -Dcucumber.filter.tags=\"@tag1 or @tag2\""
echo mvn test ${command}
mvn test ${command}
```

Now i can see the echo command in 3rd line is printing the correct command that needs to be run : `mvn test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src/main/resources/testng/runner-testng.xml -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@tag1 or @tag2"`

But for some reason its not getting executed in line number 4. Instead i am getting below errors :

```
[ERROR] Suite file /Users/****/IdeaProjects/******/src/main/resources/testng/runner-testng.xml -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@tag1 or @tag2" is not a valid file
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] Suite file /Users/*****/IdeaProjects/*****/src/main/resources/testng/runner-testng.xml -Dcucumber.filter.tags="@tag1 or @tag2" is not a valid file
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:701)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:311)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:268)
[ERROR]         at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1334)
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Which shell/terminal are you using?

Comment: I am using /bin/zsh

Comment: I do see that you are using IDEA, are you using the integrated terminal in IDEA? If so, IDEA might be do some intercepting. And mangle it.